# Azure Function Blob Trigger - Container Name as Setting

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I'm trying to create an Azure function that connects to a container that is not hard-coded, much like my connection.

```cs
  public static void Run(
[BlobTrigger("Container-Name/ftp/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream blobStream, 
string name, 
IDictionary<string, string> metaData, 
TraceWriter log)
```

The connection property is able to get the connection value directly from local.settings.json. It does not appear that capability is an option for "container-name", or if so, not with the appended /ftp/{name}.

So, is there a way to set the container name based on settings for an Azure Function Blob Trigger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define your function like this:

```cs
public static void Run(
    [BlobTrigger("%mycontainername%/ftp/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
    Stream blobStream, 
    string name, 
    IDictionary<string, string> metaData, 
    TraceWriter log)
```

and then define an application setting called `mycontainername` to contain the actual container name.

Comment: Yep. That worked. 

I tried this...  was so convinced this didnt work, but here on the second pass it seems fine. Maybe I typoed.